# <button> with JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, richfaces, tomahawk

Simple question:

Is there any way of rendering a html `<button>`-element using JSF or any other framework (RichFaces, Tomahawk etc.)? Or would I have resort to writing a custom component for this?

Comment: +1 **Great question!** I was searching for that, but it seems anyone minds about it.

Comment: A clarification: you need to write a custom **renderer**. The `h:commandButton` and the `h:commandLink` are, in fact, **the same component** (`UICommand`), but every tag uses a different renderer. So just **1)** write and register your own `<button>` renderer and **2)** register a tag that uses `UICommand` with your custom renderer.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. Since a `<button>` is usually only used in GET requests, you can also just put it plain vanilla in the JSF template. You don't need to bind any action to a JSF managed bean anyway.

In JSF 2.0, there's by the way the [`<h:button>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/button.html) which renders a GET button and offers  the option to include view parameters and/or to perform implicit navigation. Both features aren't available in JSF 1.2, so there's not really a point of having similar component in JSF 1.2 anyway.

On the other hand, if you *actually* intend to use a `<button>` to invoke a POST managed bean action method, then you should really be using a `<h:commandButton>` instead. If you're having a specific problem with it for which you thought that using `<button>` was the solution, then you'd need to reframe your question to elaborate in more detail about *that* specific problem so that we can answer how to achieve the same with `<h:commandButton>`.

Comment: AFAIK, the only difference between an <input> and a <button> is that a <button> may contain content (text, and most importantly images, which is why I want to use it). A very simple solution to this would be to let <h:commandButton> take an optional element-parameter specifying wether to render an <input> or a <button>.

Comment: And since I want the button to trigger a method in my bean, using plain vanilla html isn't really an option (unless I use it to trigger a <a4j:jsfunction>, but that seems like a really ugly solution.

Comment: If all you want is a background image for the button, just use CSS `background-image`.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but that doesn't quite cover my needs. Thanks anyway though.